# check if value is between two numbers

Tags: awk

I have a file like this

```
Start   End     Value
199146  199389  772617
377581  379032  779286
277876  279322  779287
255497  255843  809151
224415  224896  809550
246516  246946  810776
700000  800000  810777
363597  364598  810802
365242  365735  810898
454121  548113
413324  844816
```

And I would like to know for each value in column three if it is included in all intervals in columns 1 and 2.
I have to find out if the value of the 3rd column is included in one of the intervals of the first two columns. Do you have an idea? In awk? or Python?
thanks in advance

The result like this :

```
Value 772617 is found between 700000 and 800000
Value 779286 is found between 700000 and 800000
Value 779287 is found between 700000 and 800000
....
```

For now I use this but it's too redundant a solution?

```
awk -v x=772617 '$1<x && x<$2 {print x, "is contained between", $1, "and", $2}' file > file_result
```

Comment: If sounds like your requirement is that for EVERY row in column 3 ("Values"), you need to check whether it's between "Start" and "End" for EVERY  row in your dataset, from top to bottom.  In other words, it sounds like you probably need two nested loops.  Correct?  Or do you just need to check each row individually (is "Value" between "Start" and "End", for that row only)?

Comment: Yes indeed I need two nested loops, to verify that a value in column 3 is included for all intervals of the first two columns.

Comment: All of your 3rd column values are found between single range `413324` and  `844816`

Comment: do you have an idea to do this? @paulsm4

Comment: Please specify clearly: you appear to be saying you want to show the numbers in col 3 that appear in **all** intervals? or **any** interval? I can't tell what the goal is here. None of the column 3 values satisfy the first interval. Please edit your question to clearly state the requirements, and given the sample data, show what the output should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
cat file

Start   End     Value
199146  199389  772617
377581  379032  779286
277876  279322  779287
255497  255843  809151
224415  224896  809550
246516  246946  810776
700000  800000  810777
363597  364598  810802
365242  365735  810898
454121  548113
713324  810716
```

Use `awk` as:

```sh
awk '
NR > 1 {
   vals[++n] = $3
   a[$1] = $2
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
      for (k in a)
         if (vals[i] >= k && vals[i] <= a[k]) {
            print "Value", vals[i], "is found between", k, "and", a[k]
            break
         }
}' file


Value 772617 is found between 700000 and 800000
Value 779286 is found between 700000 and 800000
Value 779287 is found between 700000 and 800000
Value 809151 is found between 713324 and 810716
Value 809550 is found between 713324 and 810716
```

Comment: This does not appear to give all combinations. Strangely, I don't get the same result, but only interval "413324 .. 844816" for every third column.

Comment: I have used a slightly different input file (included above) and it caters to this requirement `I have to find out if the value of the 3rd column is included in one of the intervals of the first two columns`

Comment: Yes, the question and exact needs of "one of" vs "list all of" is vague.

Comment: btw if we remove `break` it will find all of the matching ranges

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this, where I loop every instance of column 3 through intervals. This will find all the cases.

```
BEGIN{ 
  FS=" "
  i=1 }
FNR==NR{
  # LOOP FIRST FILE
  mi[i]=$1
  mx[i]=$2
  i++
  next
}
{
  # ---- looping second file
  myval=$3
  for (j=2;j<i;j++) {
    if ((mi[j]<=myval) && (mx[j]>=myval)) {
      print $3 " is found in " mi[j] " .." mx[j]
    } 
  }
}
```

To do this, I use the `FNR==FN` check to loop over 2 files. But in this case, I loop the same file twice, first to get the values, then to compare.

```
c:\Temp>awk  -f  s.awk  data.txt   data.txt
772617 is found in 700000 ..800000
772617 is found in 413324 ..844816
779286 is found in 700000 ..800000
779286 is found in 413324 ..844816
779287 is found in 700000 ..800000
779287 is found in 413324 ..844816
809151 is found in 413324 ..844816
809550 is found in 413324 ..844816
810776 is found in 413324 ..844816
810777 is found in 413324 ..844816
810802 is found in 413324 ..844816
810898 is found in 413324 ..844816
```